# Scrolling RSS reader iPhone View

Tags: uiview, rss, uiwebview, core-animation, uitextview

I'm planning on adding a small subview to the bottom of my current app so that it can display RSS feed headlines one at a time. What would be the best type of view to use for this? `UITextView`, `UIWebView`? Perhaps a custom `UITableViewCell`? If i use a `UITextView` and tap it, it displays the keyboard, but if i `setUserInteractionEnabled` to `NO` then i wont be able to launch a different view with the article...

Scrolling each block of text would be done using core animation right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a UILabel. And yes, you will use Core Animation to animate. Here is a basic UIView animation block that will move a UILabel from the far right of the screen to the left.

```
// Set your label to display offscreen to the right
[feedLabel setCenter:CGPointMake(
                   screenWidth + [feedLabel bounds].size.width / 2, 
                   [feedLabel frame].origin.y)];

// Then later animate it into view and then off to the left.
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
// Give it 10 seconds to make it all the way across.
[UIView setAnimationDuration:10.0f];
[feedLabel setCenter:CGPointMake(
                   0.0 - [feedLabel bounds].size.width / 2, 
                   [feedLabel frame].origin.y)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Remember that the *anchorPoint* for a view such as a UILabel is the center of the view. This is why the call to *-setCenter* is taking half the width of the label to determine where the x coordinate should be. The y coordinate, of course, should just stay the same.